# Is this a typo in the retraction formula?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, self-learning

In the book, [optimization on matrix manifolds](http://www.eeci-institute.eu/GSC2011/Photos-EECI/EECI-GSC-2011-M5/book_AMS.pdf) by Absil, Chapter 3 pg 59, it is given that retraction on the orthogonal manifold $O_n$, using the Cayley's transform, is given by $$
R_{X}(X \Omega)=X\left(I-\frac{1}{2} \Omega\right)^{-1}\left(I+\frac{1}{2} \Omega\right)
$$ I am trying to derive to this from first principles but stuck mid-way.

My attempt:

Let $Q \in O_n$ and $\Omega$ be a skew symmetric matrix. By Cayley's transform, for each $\Omega$ we can find a $Q$ such that $$Q = \left( I - \Omega \right) \left( I + \Omega \right)^{-1}$$ Let $\phi$ be the mapping from $[Q^{-1},I - \Omega] \rightarrow I+\Omega$. Therefore, we can write $\pi_{1} \circ \phi^{-1}$ as matrix that takes in $I+\Omega$ and outputs $Q^{-1}$.

\begin{align}
R_{X}(X+X\Omega) &:=\pi_{1}\left(\phi^{-1}(X+X\Omega)\right) \\
& = X \pi_{1}\left(\phi^{-1}(I+\Omega)\right) \\
& = X Q^{-1} \\
& = X \left( I + \Omega \right) \left( I - \Omega \right)^{-1} \\ 
& = X \left( I - \Omega \right)^{-1} \left( I + \Omega \right)  \qquad \quad \text{as the matrices commute}\\
\end{align}

I am not sure how to get the the $\frac{1}{2}$ as mentioned in the textbook. Can you please help. Thank you.

**Update: One of the answers says that this is a typo in the book. Can others please confirm?**

Below is a picture of the relevant text and symbols. [image]

Comment: If the following papers are helpful: "A Riemannian conjugate gradient method for optimization on the Stiefel manifold", "A Feasible Method for Optimization with Orthogonality Constraints".

Answer (score 3):

An errata for *Optimization Algorithms on Matrix Manifolds* can be found at https://sites.uclouvain.be/absil/amsbook/errata.html. So far, the Cayley retraction formula on top of page 59 has been considered to be correct.

I doubt that Proposition 4.1.2 can be used here. The first step would be to clarify what $\mathcal{N}$ is, and to make sure that $\phi$ has the required domain and codomain.

**Hint**: A way to prove that
$$
R_{X}(X \Omega)=X\left(I-\frac{1}{2} \Omega\right)^{-1}\left(I+\frac{1}{2} \Omega\right)
$$
is a retraction on the orthogonal group is to confirm that it satisfies the properties given in Definition 4.1.1. The hardest part is arguably (ii) therein. Using the product rule, the chain rule and (A.3) should yield the sought result.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $\Omega$ be skew-symmetric of order $n$. Then $\frac{1}{2} \Omega$ is also skew-symmetric. Hence, by Cayley's transform there exists a $Q \in O_n$ such that
$$Q = (I - \tfrac{1}{2} \Omega) (I + \tfrac{1}{2} \Omega)^{-1}$$.

Comment: I am not sure how it helps because our input to retraction mapping is of the form $(X + X\Omega)$, not $(X + 0.5 X\Omega)$

Comment: You are right, but I don't see a problem if you redefine $R_X$ to be $$R_X(\xi) := \pi_1 (\phi^{-1}(X + \tfrac{1}{2} \xi)).$$ With that modification the proof of Proposition 4.1.2 would still work, hence it would still define a retraction.

Comment: You cannot redefine retraction as $$R_X(\xi) := \pi_1 (\phi^{-1}(X + \tfrac{1}{2} \xi))$$. The proof is for $R_X(\xi) := \pi_1 (\phi^{-1}(X + \xi))$, introducing $\frac{1}{2}$ will contradict the local rigidity property of the retraction.

Comment: Ok, nevermind.I believe there's a typo in the book.From Proposition 4.1.2 we know that $R_X(\xi) := \pi_1(\phi^{-1}(X + \xi))$ is a retraction for any $\xi$ in the neighbourhood of the origin of $T_X M$. Let's take $\xi=\tfrac{1}{2} X\Omega$.Then, by what we just said $R_X(\frac{1}{2} X\Omega)$ is a retraction and specially, let's take $\phi: (Q^{-1}, I - \frac{1}{2} \Omega) \mapsto I + \frac{1}{2} \Omega$ (obtained from the Cayley transform).Now, repeating your steps with this, you get the formula from the book except $R_X(\frac{1}{2} X\Omega)$ is on the left hand side and not $R_X(X\Omega)$.